# How to create method with parameter like: [object call:(TypeOne | TypeTwo | TypeThree)];

Tags: iphone, objective-c, methods

I'm trying to write a method in objc with a parameter that takes optional numer of types. Like the autorezise property for UIView. Or this one:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

Example:

```
[object call:(TypeOne | TypeTwo | TypeThree)];
```

My guess is to define a method that takes a enum type like this:

```
- (void)call:(EnumType)type;
```

But then i have no idea how to act on the "type". Can i use an if statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's declared as

```
typedef enum {
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeNone    = 0,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge   = 1 << 0,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound   = 1 << 1,
   UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert   = 1 << 2
} UIRemoteNotificationType;
```

there is an associated type. therefore, yes `- (void)call:(EnumType)type;` is correct.

to act on it: enum types behave like an int in many ways. you can if, compare, switch, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

To test a value of a bitfield suggested by Justin, use `&` operator:

```
if ( type & TypeOne )
    // TypeOne bit is set
```

For this to work TypeOne, TypeTwo, etc. must be integers which have exactly one bit set to 1 with the remaining bits set to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `switch` statement. And remember that enumeration of the identifiers start from **0** and increment by **1** by default. Write case statements based up on your enumeration identifier's value.